# Choose top 5 scores from multiple columns with conditions

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to automate a bowling statistics table. Each bowler has multiple games, one column for each.

The problem I am having is that I am using `=J1>=LARGE($J$3:$K$22, 4)` in conditional formatting.
I want to have it conditional for each men and women category. Also it should only calculate from the highest game of each player.

What is happening as can be seen in the uploaded file is that it is counting both scores of one player if they had two top scores.

In excel I have gotten results with the following:

```
=AND($D3<>"",D3=MAX($D3:$E3),MAX(IF($C3="M",$D3:$E3))>=LARGE(IF($C$3:$C$20="M",SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($D$3,SEQUENCE(ROWS($D$3:$E$20),1,0),,,COLUMNS($D$2:$E$2)))),4))
```

and

```
=AND($D3<>"",D3=MAX($D3:$E3),MAX(IF($C3="F",$D3:$E3))>=LARGE(IF($C$3:$C$20="F",SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($D$3,SEQUENCE(ROWS($D$3:$E$20),1,0),,,COLUMNS($D$2:$E$2)))),4))
```

When I import to sheets the function does not work

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17RxRGZdw761JGB80PmfN8IujC8KJOLYP6o8kGzJQmMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your example spreadsheet is not shared publicly.  Please change the permissions to allow access.

Comment: While a link to an external resource might be helpful, please bear in mind that questions on this site should be self contained. Considereing this, please add all the relevant details from your spreasheet including some sample data, directly into the question body.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Chances are that there are much easier ways to find those top scores. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169005/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. There is also a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: I have used the blank sheet maker to give an example of the results I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited the answer to match your updated requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the scores for the four top males like this:

```
=sortn( 
  lambda( 
    names; maxPoints; genderMatch; 
    filter({ names \ maxPoints }; genderMatch) 
  )( 
    B3:B; 
    if(D$3:D > E$3:E; D$3:D; E$3:E); 
    C$3:C = "M" 
  ); 
  4; 0; 
  2; false 
)
```

To get the scores for the top females, replace the `M` with `F`.

Then use these [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rules:

```
=($C$3:$C = "M") *  match($B3; $G$3:$G$6; 0) * match(D3; $H$3:$H$6; 0)
```

```
=($C$3:$C = "F") *  match($B3; $G$8:$G$11; 0) * match(D3; $H$8:$H$11; 0)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17RxRGZdw761JGB80PmfN8IujC8KJOLYP6o8kGzJQmMQ/edit#gid=99022090).

The sample spreadsheet is in the Vietnam locale and thus uses semicolon `;` as formula argument separator and backslash `\` as [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) horizontal separator. In the event your real spreadsheet uses comma `,` as formula argument separator, you will have to replace the backslash `\` in the formula with a comma `,`.

To answer your question, the formulas quoted in the question will only work correctly when entered as array formulas. To enter an array formula, press **Control + Shift + Enter** when editing a formula, or wrap the formula in `arrayformula()` explicitly, like this:

`=arrayformula( and($D3 <> "", D3 = max($D3:$E3), max(if($C3 = "M", $D3:$E3)) >=  large(if($C$3:$C$20 = "M", subtotal(4, offset($D$3, sequence(rows($D$3:$E$20), 1, 0), , , columns($D$2:$E$2)))), 4)) )`

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was not familiar with the lambda function. I trying to get it to work and even copying and pasting seems to give an error. I will keep studying it to get it working with my main sheet.

Comment: Edited the answer to add a note regarding spreadsheet locale. To paste the formula, open the cell for editing by selecting the cell and pressing **Enter** before pressing Control+V.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)